# How to reduce VideoView buffer with device to device RTSP streaming

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, buffering

I've rolled my own RTSP server and am currently streaming device to device - however the `VideoView` seems to be buffering 10 seconds worth of data, regardless of other parameters being set (either within code or SDP file).

Is there *any* way to reduce this?

Comment: [Probably not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413300/change-buffer-size-on-mediaplayer/4414252#4414252)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not.  It's embedded in the OS and from what I can tell there aren't any alternatives out there.