# Play live media stream on android without MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am currently using MediaPlayer to play a live stream from the web.  The problem is that the MediaPlayer buffer is huge, and it insists on buffering for around 10 seconds before playing.  [Android - MediaPlayer Buffer Size in ICS 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060165/android-mediaplayer-buffer-size-in-ics-4-0)

So my question is, is there another way to play a media stream(mp3), without using MediaPlayer?  Perhaps using an InputStream or even a third part media player that will not have the same buffering issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of 3d party libraries like FFMpeg which can easily handle mp3 files and provide much more flexibility. I suggest you to use FFMpeg or any other multimedia SDK.