# android: how to write data to media player buffer?

Tags: java, android, streaming, media-player, inputstream

I want to play live streaming media through the media player object in android.

So I'm planning on reading the buffer data from source and write it to media player's buffer, mind that I wont be using any URL for media player's stream source, the audio buffer data would be received as bytes over an input stream.

So, anybody knows appropriate way to do this

So far I can do it with audio track objects but that approach works with only uncompressed PCM data

Answer (score 2):

Follow these links this will helps you to do your work

[Android - MediaPlayer Buffer Size in ICS 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060165/android-mediaplayer-buffer-size-in-ics-4-0)

[Audio stream buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557450/audio-stream-buffering)

this will helps your