# Slow preparation on Android 2.2+ Mediaplayer - use previous version?

Tags: android

I'm about to implement an app consuming live-stream radio station resources. I've tested the [same url](http://radio-shtorm.ru:8000/56) on various platforms and noticed that  versions from 2.2 to 4.0  take a lot more time to prepare while versions below those are almost instantly playing (haven't tested for 3.0 versions thought). I suppose it's somehow related to buffer size evaluation for live-streams which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413300/change-buffer-size-on-mediaplayer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582908/why-does-it-take-so-long-for-androids-mediaplayer-to-prepare-some-live-streams).

What can I do to provide the same pre 2.2 instant preparation for all android devices ?
Thanks.

P.S. Android 4.0 prepares as good as 2.1 version - instantly.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this library http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/ solves the issue with mp3 streams but I found it useful for playing aac streams without much delay. I think, I haven't changed my mind on the dependency between bit-rate and preparation speed in case Android2.x platform: the less bit-rate it is the more time it takes to fill the internal buffer and play a stream.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm worried about the patent stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Media player preparation depends on bit rate. Details is given bellow.

1. MPR news stream: 27 seconds, 64 kbps
2. MPR classical music stream: 15 seconds, 128 kbps
3. MPR The Current stream: 7 seconds, 128 kbps
4. PRI stream: 52 seconds, 32 kbps