# MediaPlayer() audio stuttering(android)

Tags: android, media-player, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I am using the MediaPlayer function to stream a live audio stream from a remote server, in my android app. But the audio is choppy and stuttering. The problem is not my internet as the feed plays perfectly when I play it on the computer. What could be the problem?*Note: the streams are live.
This is the code I'm using:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try{
    mp.setDataSource("http://radiotool:80/feed 342.mp3");//hardcoded for testing purposes
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {Log.d("Error came up man",", check the internet connection and stuff..");
```

Comment: Have you tried to stream other mp3 files? Maybe the problem lies in this mp3, just guessing.

Comment: Yeah I tried a lot of different live streams, all have the same stuttering problem, but normal mp3 files(like songs) play perfectly...

Comment: Choppy and stuttering how often?  Like, you hear a 300ms block, then 100ms of silence, then 300ms of audio consistently?  Or, it plays for 1-3 seconds, stops for 1-3 seconds, and plays again?  How do you know this isn't a problem with the connection, maybe with WiFi?   How big is your buffer?

Comment: Yeah I hear 300ms of audio and 100ms silence, its like that.I know Wi fi is not the problem as when I play that feed in google chrome on my computer it plays perfectly. Streamed songs(on the emulator) from other websites also play perfectly. But the feed I want to play stutters. Is it because the stream is a live stream and not a song?

Comment: Live stream, pre-recorded, makes no difference.  If you are playing something over the same protocol, the player doesn't know.  The only difference is that the live stream may not initially send a giant buffer.  Usually, this doesn't matter.  Try this stream:  http://143.226.75.100/waug_mp3_128k  It's got a large buffer that is flushed to the client as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The stream you are linking to is not sending a large buffer of data at the beginning of the stream.  Normally this is not a problem, as the client is responsible for determining the rate of playback, watching the data transfer rate, and managing a client-side buffer accordingly.  That is why when I gave you a link to try that does use a large buffer, this wasn't a problem to play.

Basically, the audio dropouts are due to constant buffer underruns.  To fix this, you need to increase the buffer size.  It seems this isn't possible right now, but another method may be to [manage the HTTP client yourself and proxy the data to the MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413300/change-buffer-size-on-mediaplayer).  That link is quite old... hopefully someone has figured out how to do this another way since then.  I am not an Android developer, so I cannot tell you for sure.

What I would do first is call `mp.prepareAsync()`, and wait 2 seconds after the MediaPlayer tells you that it is ready to start.  I have a hunch that data will continue to buffer in the background until you actually call `.start()`.