# Live audio stuttering in mediaplayer()?

Tags: android, media-player, live-streaming

I am new to android. I am making a live audio streaming app(streams from a URL). As soon as I hit play, the audio plays but there is a stuttering about every half second. I checked the live audio URL on my computer and it plays perfectly. And I checked it in another audio streaming app I am making, using the same emulator, and it plays perfectly there too. The streaming file is .mp3. I have added the code.

```
    public class StreamAudioFromUrlSampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener{
    private Button btn_play,
                    btn_pause,
                    btn_stop;
    //private SeekBar seekBar;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int lengt

hOfAudio;
    private final String URL = "**some url**";
    //private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    /*private final Runnable r = new Runnable() {   
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //updateSeekProgress();                 
        }
    };*/

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        init();mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    private void init() {
        btn_play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        btn_play.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
        btn_pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
        btn_stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        btn_stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(false);

        //seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        //seekBar.setOnTouchListener(this);


        //mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        //mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
        //seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        btn_play.setEnabled(true);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            //SeekBar tmpSeekBar = (SeekBar)v;
            //mediaPlayer.seekTo((lengthOfAudio / 100) * tmpSeekBar.getProgress() );
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            //lengthOfAudio = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "error"+e);
        }

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_play:
            playAudio();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_pause:
            pauseAudio();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_stop:
            stopAudio();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        //updateSeekProgress();
    }

    private void updateSeekProgress() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            //seekBar.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / lengthOfAudio) * 100));
        //  handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
        }
    }

    private void stopAudio() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        btn_play.setEnabled(true);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
        mediaPlayer.release();
        //seekBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    private void pauseAudio() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        btn_play.setEnabled(true);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void playAudio() {try{
        Thread.sleep(10000);}catch(InterruptedException x){}
        mediaPlayer.start();
        btn_play.setEnabled(false);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(true);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you run the code on emulator or on real device? Emulator is not a good idea to check stuff like MediaPlayer especially under windows.

Comment: I run it on the emulator, but like I said I tried playing the url in 2 different apps, both on the emulator, and it plays perfectly on one app and stutters on the other. That means that emulator is not at fault. And yeah it stutters on a real device too(galaxy note 2).

Comment: there is nothing in your code that could cause stuttering. It comes from MediaPlayer I believe. And the reason could be network or stream or something else in your code (some background process/service). However I can't see setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

Comment: i added that line, still stuttering..

Comment: If you are the developer of the second app which plays that stream with no stuttering so why just not to compare code or just use a working good code? Also this Thread.sleep(10000) (stops mainUI thread) is no good and seamless and you'd better use prepareAsync instead of usual prepare(stops mainUI thread) and also add an onError listener maybe it will say something useful. Also place some logging code lines in onBufferingUpdate maybe you'll catch some connection with stuttering

Comment: also the following link might be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439895/mediaplayer-audio-stutteringandroid?rq=1