# Change buffering size/interval for MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am streaming audio using `MediaPlayer` on Android.
I want my app to change buffering interval if network is slow i.e. initially cache 5% of song before starting playback than if all cached data already played but new portion is not ready yet cache next 10% and so on. The main point is to avoid song continually stopping and restarting on a slow network.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413300/change-buffer-size-on-mediaplayer) topic I can't change buffer size for `MediaPlayer`. Maybe someone has any other idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are not way to change buffer size of [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) unless you are the hardware driver provider of the device.

The [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class is a kind of wrapper to C++ implementation. E.g. if you call `myMediaPlayer.seekTo(123)` you are calling a C++ method through Java code.

```
public native void seekTo(int msec) throws IllegalStateException;
```

Source of [android.media.MediaPlayer.seekTo(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer.seekTo%28int%29).

---

I recommend you to allow user start the audio after load a certain percentage of buffer.

You can track how many of audio was buffered with [`onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html) listener.

So after [prepared state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) and audio buffer get a certain percent e.g. 50% you could start the audio.