# Click an image button match with sound effect

Tags: android, button, soundeffect, animator

The code below is to click an Image button with some animation, at the same time it with a sound effect. 
Problem is the sound track doesn't match with the button click when I repeat clicking the button, the sound effect delayed and doesn't match with the number of clicking.

[Class file] // the sound track get from res/raw/track.mp3

```
final MediaPlayer click= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track);

    btn1= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    txt1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate));
            click.start();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using a `SoundPool`.
Try this:

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer,     Integer>();
soundPoolMap.put(soundID, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.your_sound, 1));
```

And then play your sound using

```
soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
```

This answer is linked to this post:[POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058862/delay-between-button-click-and-sound)

Comment: Thx for the info dude, but I did some tweak on it. 

SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
int soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.track, 1);
soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);