# MediaPlayer start delay when click on button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play mp3 file from res/raw folder when user click on button

**my code is below:**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
        R.raw.click);
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Work well but take some time to play after button click. please, anyone, give me a solution. 
Thanks

Comment: put this   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                    R.raw.click); in onCreate() and just start media player in onclick callback

Comment: Thanks for answer, i'll try it and will tell you if work well.

Comment: I would recommend not using MediaPlayer and use ExoPlayer instead. It is extendable, stable and can play many different types of media. You can find it here: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/

Comment: First solution work great for me!! Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, you can do mp.prepare() after create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Instead of creating the media player and then calling **start()** method in the **onClick** of the button, you can initialize the mediaPlayer in onCreate() of activity.

As for the button click implementation, you need to call **mediaPlayer.start()** only.

**Option 2:**
You can use [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) API provided by Android. This has lower latency compared to MediaPlayer API. SoundPool are recommended mainly for playing short clips.

Comment: @SahdevRajput74 If any answer is helpful to you and solve your problem then you can mark as correct : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGNzO.png

Answer (score 2):

Loading time depends on the buffer size of the MediaPlayer (which is hardcoded in the firmware) and that there is nothing that can be done to change it. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6583241/2550246).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

This is as a result of the [buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413300/change-buffer-size-on-mediaplayer) of media player.

Try using [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) for a more responsive playback. You can see an implementation of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058862/delay-between-button-click-and-sound).

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
soundPoolMap.put(soundID, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.click, 1));
```

Start the sound with `soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what value i can give to soundID??

Comment: If you have only a single audio clip to be played, then you can do:
int soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.click, 1);
soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);